# android gridview with edittext inside listview lose focus

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-edittext

I have a listview with gridview in each row, the gridview has many edit text items, when i want to write in one of edittexts (gridview items), it will lose focus and the activity jump to the top.

Comment: Nested scrollable Views are really a **bad** idea.

Comment: try this     android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants":

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

in your manifest add this to your listView activity.

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

and for the listview in layout add this.

```
 android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
```